# Music not playing in Discord voice channel

Tags: java, spring-boot, discord, discord4j, lavaplayer

I'm trying to add the functionality of playing music to my custom Discord bot.
I'm writing it in Java 11, Spring Boot, Discord4j and the LavaPlayer library.

I have the command !join that makes the Discord bot join the voice channel of the person who typed the command. This works but I assign the `LavaPlayerAudioProvider` to the `VoiceState` once the bot joins. So the mistake might occur here (I don't know). This is the class for the !join command:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JoinCommandHandler implements CommandStrategy {
    private final LavaPlayerAudioProvider provider;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * Makes the bot join the voice channel of the user.
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> execute(Message message) {
        return Mono.just(message)
                .flatMap(Message::getAuthorAsMember)
                .flatMap(m -> m.getVoiceState()
                        .flatMap(VoiceState::getChannel))
                .flatMap(c -> c.join(spec -> spec.setProvider(provider)))
                .then();
    }

    @Override
    public String getCommandName() {
        return "!join";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "**Under Development** Make this bot join your channel.";
    }
}
```

To be honest, I don't think the mistake is going to be in the !join command but it might be usefull to understand the question more.

I have the audio configurations set in the `AudioConfig` class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AudioConfig {
    @Bean
    public AudioPlayerManager audioPlayerManager() {
        final AudioPlayerManager playerManager = new DefaultAudioPlayerManager();
        playerManager.getConfiguration().setFrameBufferFactory(NonAllocatingAudioFrameBuffer::new);
        AudioSourceManagers.registerLocalSource(playerManager);
        return playerManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public AudioPlayer audioPlayer() {
        return audioPlayerManager().createPlayer();
    }

    @Bean
    public AudioProvider audioProvider() {
        return new LavaPlayerAudioProvider(audioPlayer());
    }
}
```

I wrote a !play [youtube url] command to play music once the bot joined a voice channel.

```
@Service("!play")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlayCommand implements CommandStrategy {
    private final AudioPlayerManager manager;
    private final TrackScheduler trackScheduler;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * Makes the bot queue a song and play in the channel.
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> execute(Message message) {
        return Mono.just(message.getContent())
                .map(content -> Arrays.asList(content.split(" ")))
                .doOnNext(command -> manager.loadItem(command.get(1), trackScheduler)).then();
    }
}
```

And here the `LavaPlayerAudioProviver` to provide the music:

```
@Component
public final class LavaPlayerAudioProvider extends AudioProvider {
    private final AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
    private final MutableAudioFrame frame = new MutableAudioFrame();

    public LavaPlayerAudioProvider(AudioPlayer audioPlayer) {
        super(ByteBuffer.allocate(StandardAudioDataFormats.DISCORD_OPUS.maximumChunkSize()));
        this.frame.setBuffer(getBuffer());
        this.audioPlayer = audioPlayer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean provide() {
        final boolean didProvide = audioPlayer.provide(frame);
        if (didProvide) {
            getBuffer().flip();
        }
        return didProvide;
    }
}
```

Now here comes the tricky part. I debugged the code to see step by step how the code executes after I type the !play [url] command.

When the code reaches the `TrackScheduler` class, it doesn't execute the `trackLoaded()` method to play the song, instead it executes the `noMatches()` method, which basically means the URL can not be found and thus no music can be played. You can find the `TrackScheduler` class here:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TrackScheduler implements AudioLoadResultHandler {
    private final AudioPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void trackLoaded(final AudioTrack track) {
        // LavaPlayer found an audio source for us to play
        player.playTrack(track);
    }

    @Override
    public void playlistLoaded(final AudioPlaylist playlist) {
        // LavaPlayer found multiple AudioTracks from some playlist
    }

    @Override
    public void noMatches() {
        // LavaPlayer did not find any audio to extract
    }

    @Override
    public void loadFailed(final FriendlyException exception) {
        // LavaPlayer could not parse an audio source for some reason
    }
}
```

I tried different URLs but they all end up going in the noMatch() method...
I followed the Discord4J guide (https://docs.discord4j.com/music-bot-tutorial) but they're not using Spring Boot so it's a little puzzle..

If you need more info, I'll be glad to give it to you.
Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know its a bit late but here you go.

Your problem is, that you are registering only local sources for audioplayer. That means, that lavaplayer does not know what are sites like *Facebook*, *Youtube* or *Vimeo* and how to process them.

You should add  `AudioSourceManagers.registerRemoteSources(audioPlayerManager);` to your configuration class.

So final configuration class will look like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class AudioConfig {
    @Bean
    public AudioPlayerManager audioPlayerManager() {
        final AudioPlayerManager playerManager = new DefaultAudioPlayerManager();
        playerManager.getConfiguration().setFrameBufferFactory(NonAllocatingAudioFrameBuffer::new);
        AudioSourceManagers.registerLocalSource(playerManager);
        AudioSourceManagers.registerRemoteSources(audioPlayerManager);
        return playerManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public AudioPlayer audioPlayer() {
        return audioPlayerManager().createPlayer();
    }

    @Bean
    public AudioProvider audioProvider() {
        return new LavaPlayerAudioProvider(audioPlayer());
    }
}
```

Other that that, your code works fine for me. And I would suggest removing `AudioSourceManagers.registerLocalSource(playerManager);` altogether, I dont see any reason why expose server side files this way.